# SharePoint 2010 - Enterprise Wiki Custom Site Template 404 error

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I've ran into an issue where I save a enterprise wiki site as a template, then when I go to create a site based on the site template that I just created, once finish, I get a 404 page. It seems like once the site is created sharepoint can't find the home page. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Watch ULS logs, probably something went wrong during the site deployment.
Good tool for log analyzing http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/ULSViewer